# Building Qt for iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qt5

I'm trying to go through the following tutorial to get a simple sample Qt app running on the iOS simulator.

https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/03/05/qt-for-ios-preview

I get to step 3 and run the following commmand

```
./configure -xplatform unsupported/macx-ios-clang -developer-build -nomake examples -nomake tests -release [-sdk iphonesimulator]
```

I get back the following

```
[-sdk: unknown argument iphonesimulator]: unknown argument
```

Note: I'm on a mac with XCode installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[-sdk iphonesimulator]` didn't work for me, I had to strip the brackets off.

Answer (score 1):

the -sdk values come from `$ xcodebuild -showsdks`